# htaccess authentication rest api methods

Tags: .htaccess, rest, http, authentication, http-authentication

I have REST API service built using CakePHP and I need to protect some of my methods using http authentication. For example I have methods like:

```
POST /api/store
{
   name: "John",
   surname: "Johnny",
   ...
}
```

and I want to protect this particular path (/api/store) to protect with http authentication to call cron job

```
http://username:password@server.com/api/store
```

is sth like that possible? If so, then how? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this. As long as that url /api/store is not physical path, we need to make different approach thank using basic http auth secured folder.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/api/store protected_method=true
# we need to match url with regex and set it to "protected_method" variable    

# Commom auth
AuthUserFile /absolute/path/to/directory/of/api
AuthName "This method is pwd protected"
AuthType Basic

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any

Require valid-user
#check if requested url is one of protected_method
Allow from env=!protected_method
```